# Where are the birds?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm level 25 in Skyrim and I don't think I've seen a single bird.  I've had some bats fly past me once or twice, but that's about it.

These areas, with the mountains and beautiful terrain, birds should be flying everywhere.

Comment: I like this question purely because you are in a world of dragons, assassins, thieves, mages and warriors, and what are you after... the local RSPB reserve :)

Comment: Chickens seem pretty common...

Answer (score 3):

The birds are in the sky!

But seriously, it depends on the draw distance if you see birds or not, the most chance of seeing them is if you look straight at the sky, on a place that is located not too low, under clear day skies.

Also they're not always there, but added semi-randomly, and birds and dragons usually don't share the same territory.

Personally I sometimes only notice the birds because of their shadows when they fly over me.

Comment: -1 Not all birds are in the sky, some birds are flightless. Penguins are a prime example.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I have my settings on ultra and haven't even seen a bird shadow.  I would love to see birds circling over my head.  I'll keep looking for them.  I'll check some of my other settings but I think they are all maxed.

Comment: @DrZ Try Solitude. I feel like there are always several hawks overhead there. I see them on ultra-low settings.

Comment: Went to Solitude and found the hawk.  I'll keep my eyes open in other areas!

Comment: @agf Also, the feathers of those hawks are one of the easiest sources of Cure Disease potions (along with mudcrabs). So there are birds _and_ they're useful. :)